How to remove FIRST occurence of substring from a string?
I am working on and can only work with a batch file. No PowerShell.
I would like to remove the FIRST occurrence of a substring in a string.
@echo off 
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "str=C:\help\te\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example"  

echo -----------Original string--------------------------- 
echo !str!  
 
echo ----------This removes EVERY \te\---------------------------- 
echo !str:\te\=\!  
 
echo -----------This gets everything after first \te\--------------------------- 
set "strAfter=!str:*\te\=\!"
echo !strAfter!  

echo ----------This gets everything before first \te\---------------------------- 
echo how?  

echo ---------simply get rid of FIRST \te\----------------------------- 
echo how?  

echo -----------------I could work with the position of the first \te\------------------------------- 
echo how?  

PAUSE

I've played with what is above. I've played with for loop, find, findstr.
I've also thought of getting the position of the first \te\ and then proceed with extracting the string before and the string after and finally concatenating. No success with anything.
UPDATE 1: With Magoo's trick, I'm able to make it work. Thank you. (Still reading up on double quotes, %%, && and !!.)
echo:
echo ------ This gets everything before first \te\--------
rem Replace "everything after \te\" with nothing, then remove \te again
set "strBefore=!str:%strAfter%=!"
set "strBefore=!strBefore:\te=!"
echo !strBefore!

echo:
echo ------ First method--------
set "finalstr=!strBefore!!strAfter!"
echo !finalStr!

I'm still curious to getting a position if ever I need it.
echo:
echo ----(Method2)-- I could work with the position of the first \te\-------- 
echo ------ if I could get the 7 automatically
set /a ind=7
set before=!str:~0,%ind%!
set after=!str:*\te\=\!
set finalstr=!before!!after!
echo !finalstr!

And curious, there is really no easy 1 or 2 line search for FIRST occurrence?
UPDATE 2: While the small testing script above worked, once I brought it back into the actual script, it breaks. Here's the official script.
@ECHO off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 


REM find filenames that are links
For /R %%G in (*.lnk) do (
   echo: 
   echo --------------------------------
   set originalLink=%%G
   echo For this link  : !originalLink!
   
   REM find the Target/cible
   for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('shortcutJS.bat -examine "%%G" ^| find /i "Target:"') do (
      set "targetVar=%%a"        
   )
   REM remove word Target: from front (use double quotes in case of spaces)
   set "targetVar=!targetVar:Target:=!"    
   echo Target file is : !targetVar! 

   rem TODO count how many \te\ to put an if to skip if useless

   REM remove or replace the FIRST folder named \te\ from path
   set "strAfter=!targetVar:*\te\=\!"
   echo strAfter first \te\: !strAfter!

   REM Replace "everything after \te\" with nothing, then remove \te again
   set "strBefore=!targetVar:%strAfter%=!"
   echo strBefore is: !strBefore!
   set "strBefore=!strBefore:\te=!"
   echo strBefore: !strBefore!
   set "targetNew=!strBefore!!strAfter!"
   echo targetNew !targetNew!

   REM this would remove every \te\... not good if more than one. trying to change with what's above.
   set targetNew=!targetVar:\te\=\!
   echo:
   echo New target     : !targetNew!

   REM actually push the new Target to the file...
   REM editShortcut.vbs "!originalLink!" "!targetNew!"
    
   PAUSE
)

strAfter works, but not strBefore. Here is one output:
--------------------------------
For this link  : C:\Users\carol\Desktop\tests raccourcis names serveur\renameLinks2\horloge velo.jpg.lnk
Target file is : C:\Users\carol\Desktop\tests raccourcis names serveur\te\horloge velo.jpg
strAfter first \te\: \horloge velo.jpg
strBefore is: targetVar:=
strBefore: targetVar:=
targetNew targetVar:=\horloge velo.jpg

New target     : C:\Users\carol\Desktop\tests raccourcis names serveur\horloge velo.jpg
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...


Please don't post graphics of code or results as this means we have to retype the data with the danger of tyops. On Win10+, you can simply select the relevant text and right-click the mouse to copy the text to the clipboard ready to post.

Thank you for the fix. I didn't think of any reason copy/pasting the output would be useful, but indeed when replying why "this output line" is wrong. Understood.

This one-liner works here:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=C:\help\te\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example"
echo Old: "%str%"

set "repl=\" & set "new=%str:\te\=!repl!" & set "repl=\te\" & set "new=!new!%"
echo New: "%new%"

Output:
Old: "C:\help\te\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example"
New: "C:\help\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example"

For a further description on the method used, see this answer
You can also get the position of the first (or all) \te\ string using this similar method

EDIT: New method added as response to comment
The method above requires to use %standard% expansion in order to work. If you want to perform this replacement into a loop (that would require !delayed! expansion), you have two options:
1- Use a subroutine to perform the replacement
Just define a subroutine that get the string in the parameter, perform the replacement and returns the result in a variable, and call it from inside the loop:
:replaceFirst
set "str=%~1"
set "repl=\" & set "new=%str:\te\=!repl!" & set "repl=\te\" &  set "new=!new!%"
exit /B

2- Replace the delimiter substring by a new-line character, and process the parts in a standard for /F command:
set "new="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!str:\te\^=^
%Don't remove this line%
!^") do (
   if not defined new (
      set "new=%%a\"
   ) else (
      set "new=!new!%%a\te\"
   )
)
set "new=!new:~0,-4!"

Below is the complete code that solve your problem:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM find filenames that are links
For /R %%G in (*.lnk) do (
   echo: 
   echo --------------------------------
   set originalLink=%%G
   echo For this link  : !originalLink!
   
   REM find the Target/cible
   for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('shortcutJS.bat -examine "%%G" ^| find /i "Target:"') do (
      set "targetVar=%%a"        
   )
   REM remove word Target: from front (use double quotes in case of spaces^)
   set "targetVar=!targetVar:Target:=!"    
   echo Target file is : !targetVar! 

   rem TODO count how many \te\ to put an if to skip if useless

   REM remove or replace the FIRST folder named \te\ from path
   set "targetNew="
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!targetVar:\te\^=^
%Don't remove this line%
!^") do (
      if not defined targetNew (
         set "targetNew=%%a\"
      ) else (
         set "targetNew=!targetNew!%%a\te\"
      )
   )
   set "targetNew=!targetNew:~0,-4!"

   echo:
   echo New target     : !targetNew!

   REM actually push the new Target to the file...
   REM editShortcut.vbs "!originalLink!" "!targetNew!"
    
   PAUSE
)

EDIT #2: Simpler method added
The following code is a much simpler solution:
   REM remove or replace the FIRST folder named \te\ from path
   for %%a in ("!targetVar:*\te\=!") do set "targetNew=!targetVar:\te\%%~a=!\%%~a"

   echo:
   echo New target     : !targetNew!


After finally understanding this with echo on, I gave this a shot in the loop. It does not work. Is it the same issue that Magoo mentions above: The for loop replaces str (in my case targetVar) before execution and certainly not the changed value in the loop? I did    set "repl=" & set "new=%targetVar:\te=!repl!" & set "repl=\te" & set "new=!new!%" and tried    set "repl=" & set "new=%!targetVar!:\te=!repl!" & set "repl=\te" & set "new=!new!%". no luck.

Well, my code solves your problem as you originally stated it. You didn't say that the replacement requires delayed expansion (because the values will be processed inside a for loop). See the EDIT in my answer... NOTE: You should not include extensive descriptions in your question about the fails in other answers... This just make your question more difficult to understand...

I added a new simpler method. See the EDIT #2...

EDIT 2 is perfect. It does bug if no \te\ found, but I'll put an if. Thank you.

I suggest the following commented code to get a file/folder name string with first directory with name te removed from the string.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "str=C:\help\te\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example"

rem Replace all \te\ by | in the string which no file/folder name
rem can have ever at all. There could be used also ? or other
rem characters not allowed in a file/folder name except *. 
set "str=%str:\te\=|%"

rem Split up the file/folder name string never beginning with
rem a semicolon into two parts: the string left to first | and
rem the remaining part with zero or more vertical bars. Then
rem concatenate the two strings with a backslash between theme.
for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%I in ("%str%") do set "str=%%I\%%J"

rem Replace all still existing | back to \te\ to get the resulting string.
set "str=%str:|=\te\%"
set str
pause
endlocal

The output of this batch file is:
str=C:\help\Windows\Example\001 Example\te\005 Example

This code can be used in the rewritten main batch file.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Find file names of shortcut files.
for /R %%G in (*.lnk) do (
   echo(
   echo --------------------------------
   echo For this shortcut: %%G
   rem Find the target/cible.
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %%I in ('^""%~dp0shortcutJS.bat" -examine "%%G" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "Target:"^"') do set "targetNew=%%J"
   echo Target file is:    !targetNew!
   rem Remove the first folder with name te from new target string.
   set "targetNew=!targetNew:\te\=|!
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%I in ("!targetNew!") do set "targetNew=%%I\%%J"
   set "targetNew=!targetNew:|=\te\!"
   echo The new target is: !targetNew!
   rem %SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //B //NoLogo "%~dp0editShortcut.vbs" "%%G" "!targetNew!"
   pause
)
endlocal

There are some modifications in main batch file not related to the question. Some of theme are described by the issue chapters in this answer.
The batch file shortcutJS.bat (most likely a BAT/JS hybrid or a BAT/VBS hybrid with miss-leading file name) and the VBScript file editShortcut.vbs are most likely in the same directory as the main batch file and are referenced for that reason with their fully qualified file names. The current working directory on batch file execution can be with this modification any directory in which a recursive search for shortcut files with file extension .lnk is done by the first FOR loop.
ATTENTION: The code of main batch file does not work if any shortcut file name contains one or more ! or any target output by shortcutJS.bat contains one or more exclamation marks due to permanently enabled delayed variable expansion. An exclamation mark in a string assigned to the loop variables G, I and J is interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference resulting in an appropriate modification of this string before being further processed resulting in wrong file name/target string processing.

Given the sample names:
   rem use constant value in place of '%%G'
   
   set "targetVar=Target:c:\Users\Carol\tests raccoursis names serveur\te\horlorge velo.jpg"        
   REM remove word Target: from front (use double quotes in case of spaces)
   set "targetVar=!targetVar:Target:=!"    
   echo Target file is : !targetVar! 

   rem TODO count how many \te\ to put an if to skip if useless

   REM remove or replace the FIRST folder named \te\ from path
   set "strAfter=!targetVar:*\te\=!"
   echo strAfter first \te\: !strAfter!

   REM Replace "everything after \te\" with nothing, then remove \te\ again
   CALL :removete
   echo strBefore is: !strBefore!
rem   set "strBefore=!strBefore:\te=!"
rem   echo strBefore: !strBefore!
   ECHO this is without the REPLACEment FOR \te\
   set "targetNew=!strBefore!!strAfter!"
   echo targetNew !targetNew!
   
   ECHO this is with a REPLACEment FOR \te\
   set "targetNew=!strBefore!\replacement directory\!strAfter!"
   echo targetNew !targetNew!

After the final ) line,
GOTO :EOF

:removete
set "strBefore=!targetVar:\te\%strAfter%=!"
GOTO :eof

Notes:
I prefer to explicitly insert constant \ as needed instead of juggling with leading/trailing characters in variables' values. IMHO, it makes the processing easier to design and maintain. YMMV.
In your code, you used
   set "strBefore=!targetVar:%strAfter%=!"

In that statement, %strAfter% would be replaced by the value of strAfter at the time the for statement was encountered - before execution and certainly not the changed value in the loop. Variables are not behaving as expected
Note the call to the internal subroutine removete. The colon is required (marks the routine as internal).
The label :EOF (case-insensitive, but the colon is required) in built-in to mean End Of File. Reaching end-of-file terminates a subroutine or the main routine if no subroutine is in progress.


"In that statement, %strAfter% would be replaced by the value of strAfter at the time the for statement was encountered - before execution and certainly not the changed value in the loop. Variables are not behaving as expected" UNDERSTOOD. hence why it worked in the mini code but not inside the for loop. I had replaced the %% by !! without success, but I  suppose there is not way to apply delayedExpension in that instance?. 2) Am I to understand that since you put the one command in the internal subroutine, it overrides that issue?



Not that I can see. 2) The subroutine operates on the run-time values of the variables, effectively executing `set "strBefore=!!targetVar:!strAfter!=!!"``

